# I can't seem to remove a file even after changing ownership and permissions

Tags: permissions, rm, chmod

Haven't been here much. Mostly Stackoverflow. Anyway, I have a file that I can't remove.

I tried `sudo rm files.db` and got

```
Operation not permitted
```

Did `sudo chown me: files.db`

Then `sudo chmod 777 files.db`

Tried `sudo rm files.db` again and got same result.

`ls -l` produces:

```
-rwx------  1 me  staff  34177024 Jun  6 23:58 files.db
```

I had hoped to see:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 me  staff  34177024 Jun  6 23:58 files.db
```

Tried `sudo chflags noschg files.db`

Then `sudo chmod 777 files.db` and then still got:

```
-rwx------  1 me  staff  34177024 Jun  6 23:58 files.db
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Tried `su user rm -rf files.db` put in my password and got:

```
su: Sorry
```

I used this drive for Time Machine backups.

Isn't there some way to force a removal?

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Not sure how this works but tried `ls -i` and got:

```
5482053549 files.db
```

Then `find . -inum 5482053549 -delete` and got:

```
find: -delete: unlink(./files.db): Operation not permitted
```

Also tried `find . -inum 5482053549 -exec rm {} \;` and got:

```
rm: ./files.db: Operation not permitted
```

Ugh.

LAST UPDATE:

This morning I did the following: `chown me folder` and then `chmod 777 folder`. I was then was able to delete the file.

Comment: What's the filesystem this is on? Is it a networked one? (The file server could easily say "I'm not letting you change this, no matter who you are".)

Comment: Yes, it is a 1T drive I use to backup some work. I've deleted many other files from the drive. So maybe if I connect it directly it may work? I'll give it a try in the AM... gotta hit the sack. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have write permission on the directory?  Is the file in use?

Comment: `su` requires the root password, not your own password.

Comment: if you do a `lsattr` on the file is the immutable attribute set on the file? The tip-off for me was the fact that you're sudo'ing to root and it's still denying you. root has CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE (or whatever the equivalent on OS X is) so I don't think it's a permissions issue. On Linux immutable is handled by a separate CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability which only affects `chattr` invocations. There's probably a similar idea in the BSD/OS X world.

Comment: @tripleee you had the answer. If you enter it as an answer, I'll credit you with the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also try `chflags nouchg`, or did you check if some parent directory had a `uchg` or `schg` flag?

```
$ mkdir 1; touch 1/2; chflags uchg 1; sudo rm -f 1/2
rm: 1/2: Operation not permitted
$ chflags nouchg 1; rm 1/2
$
```

If there wasn't write permission to the directory, the error message would usually be `Permission denied` instead of `Operation not permitted`:

```
$ sudo mkdir 3; sudo touch 3/4; sudo chown $USER 3/4; rm 3/4
rm: 3/4: Permission denied
```

`sudo rm` normally works even if the `delete` or `delete_child` operations are denied:

```
$ touch 4; chmod +a 'everyone deny delete' 4; rm 4
rm: 4: Permission denied
$ mkdir 5; touch 5/6; chmod +a 'everyone deny delete_child' 5; rm 5/6
rm: 5/6: Permission denied
$ ls -lde 4 5
-rw-r--r--+ 1 lauri  staff    0 Jun  7 12:44 4
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 lauri  staff  102 Jun  7 12:44 5
 0: group:everyone deny delete_child
$ sudo rm 4 5/6
$
```